# The requested URL was not found on this server. Magento with oAuth

Tags: php, magento, oauth, magento-1.9

I'm using magento CE version. And i want to script my local Magento ecommerce site with php. My magento Community edition version file system does not includes oAuth directory so my script is not find oAuth url. My codes like this->

```
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $magentoUrl . 'oauth/token';
$adminAuthorizationUrl = $magentoUrl . 'admin/oauth_authorize';
$apiUrl = $magentoUrl . 'api/rest';
```

But Oauth, admin and api files does not exist in my "opt/lamp/htdocs/magento" directory so error occurs like topic. Is there a difference between Magento Enterprice edition(EE) and Community Edition files? Magento(EE) includes those oAuth files ? Which url path values we must use in (CE) version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change magente url like this $magentoUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/'; Other variables are correct not change them.

Comment: Ty Lutfiye. I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and now it works. Url is correct.